# How can I split a data table based on column count in c#

Tags: c#, split, datatable, dataset

[image]

I have this datatable which I want to split into 2 different datatables and save them in a dataset. This datatable may have contain more columns like these. I want a dynamic solution to do this.

Comment: Did you try anything to solve this problem? What's the issue you are facing? Can you share the code?

Comment: And then what will you do to keep your data together?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could start by making a copy of the data table

```
var tbl1 = YourDataSet.Tables["whateverTableOrIndex"];
var tbl2 = tbl1.DefaultView.ToTable();
```

// Now, from table 1, you can REMOVE all columns AFTER column 6

```
while( tbl1.Columns.Count > 6 )
   tbl1.Columns.RemoveAt(6)
```

// Then, from the second table, remove the first 5 columns

```
for( int i; i < 5; i++ )
   tbl2.Columns.RemoveAt(0);
```

Comment: thanks for understanding my problem this should be the best answer I can get